# How do I create protocol extensions that work with enums that have been initialized?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, duplicates, protocols

I have an `enum` used in `class` `DoorModeModel`:

```
enum DoorModeName: String {
    case off = "MODE_OFF"
    case exit = "MODE_EXIT"
    case auto = "MODE_AUTO"
    case partial = "MODE_PARTIAL"
    case open = "MODE_OPEN"
}
```

Then there are two different targets in the app that use different descriptions. I put these in extensions based on target:

```
extension DoorModeModel.DoorModeName {
    var presentableName: String {
        switch self {
        case .off: return "MODE_OFF".localized()
        case .exit: return "MODE_EXIT".localized()
        case .auto: return "MODE_AUTO".localized()
        case .partial: return "MODE_PARTIAL".localized()
        case .open: return "MODE_OPEN".localized()
        }
    }
}
```

Then the other extension:

```
extension DoorModeModel.DoorModeName {
    var presentableName: String {
        switch self {
        case .off: return "MODE_OFF_2".localized()
        case .exit: return "MODE_EXIT_2".localized()
        case .auto: return "MODE_AUTO_2".localized()
        case .partial: return "MODE_PARTIAL_2".localized()
        case .open: return "MODE_OPEN_2".localized()
        }
    }
}
```

Works great. Then there is a similar, but slightly different `enum` used in another part of the app, `DoorModeService`:

```
enum OperatingModeName: Int {
    case off = 0
    case exit = 1
    case auto = 2
    case partial = 3
    case open = 4   
}
```

Like before, there are different descriptions based on the `target`. And like before I created `extensions` for them. The code is exactly the same as the two `extensions` above, save for extending a different `enum`:

```
extension DoorModeService.OperatingModeName {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        ...
```

I don't want duplicate code, so I'm trying to find a way to use the same `enum` descriptions for both `enums`. I thought it would be possible to do this using `protocol extensions` but since the `extensions` aren't aware of the `enums,` I don't see how this would work:

```
protocol EnumDescription {
    var description: String { get }
}

extension EnumDescription {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .off: return "MODE_OFF".localized()
        case .exit: return "MODE_EXIT".localized()
        case .auto: return "MODE_AUTO".localized()
        case .partial: return "MODE_PARTIAL".localized()
        case .open: return "MODE_OPEN".localized()
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the error `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'x'`
Do I set the `extension` to conform to `enums`, something like:

```
extension EnumDescription where self == enumSomething
```

Or how do I go about using the same descriptions for the two `enums` I have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `static` property requirements with type `Self` for all common cases between the 2 `enum`s on your protocol to be able to switch over them in the implementation of `description`.

```
protocol ModeName: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable {
    static var off: Self { get }
    static var exit: Self { get }
    static var auto: Self { get }
    static var partial: Self { get }
    static var open: Self { get }
}

extension ModeName {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .off: return "MODE_OFF".localized()
        case .exit: return "MODE_EXIT".localized()
        case .auto: return "MODE_AUTO".localized()
        case .partial: return "MODE_PARTIAL".localized()
        case .open: return "MODE_OPEN".localized()
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
}

enum DoorModeName: String, ModeName {
    case off = "MODE_OFF"
    case exit = "MODE_EXIT"
    case auto = "MODE_AUTO"
    case partial = "MODE_PARTIAL"
    case open = "MODE_OPEN"
}

enum OperatingModeName: Int, ModeName {
    case off = 0
    case exit = 1
    case auto = 2
    case partial = 3
    case open = 4   
}
```

Comment: Seems like a sound approach, but I still get the same error: "Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'x'" as the extensions are unaware of the enum. How do I make them aware of the enum?

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt check my updated answer, now it should work fine